# Custom options, create order in backend, uses default prices instead of store prices

Tags: admin, orders, custom-options

When setting up a custom options with website level prices and creating an order in the admin, at first, it shows the right price, but when selecting the billing country it resets the price to use the default custom option price.

Example: I have a product that costs 100$. The custom option for US website costs 240$ and the default value is 20$. At first the price is shown correctly: 340$, but when selecting USA as a country for the customer it goes to 120$.

Prices are set at website level.

Any idea why this is happening? Tried in base magento theme and it has the same behaviour. The frontend works as expected, just the backend is the issue.

Update: I tried it in versions 1.7 and 1.9 on different websites, disabled all modules etc. Anyone can recreate the issue? Is it a magento bug or a setting in the admin that I'm missing?

Update 2: After further digging I've found something that might point to the error. When selecting the country, `prototype.js` is fired with this ajax call:

```
POST http://website/index.php/admin/sales_o...ey/96...21/shipping_method/billing_method/totals/giftmessage/items?isAjax=true
```

and there is this html response:

```
{"shipping_method":"
\n
\n
<\/div>\n
Shipping Method<\/h4>\n <\/div>\n
\n
\n \n Get shipping methods and rates <\/a>\n \n <\/div>\n
Shipping method selection is not applicable<\/span><\/div>\n
```

If I add another product it works as expected, so the error appears only for the first product.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello please put your second update as your answer for this question and feel free to accept it.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy Thanks for your interest in my question. Unfortunately it is not an answer, but merely possibly just pointing to the error. The issue still appears when adding the first product in the order.